# ORMLite handle uniqueCombo constraint fail exception

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, exception, ormlite

I have a couple of columns in my database which has been annotated as uniqueCombo=true

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "COL1", uniqueCombo = true)
private Double col1;

@DatabaseField(columnName = "COL2", uniqueCombo = true)
private Double col2;
```

According to ormlite documentation the combination of these two fields should be unique in the table. To test this I am purposely adding same fields. I do get the SQLException but am not sure how do I handle this exception and ask the user to make changes.

```
try {
        mydao.create(myInfo);

     } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

       e.printStackTrace();
       /* Need to uniquely identify constraint failed error here
        * and ask user to make suitable change */
     }
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished.

-- UPDATE ---

SQLException getErrorCode and getSQLState both return 0 and null respectively.

Logcat StackTrace:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column NAME is not unique (code 19)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.insert(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:122)
01-31 22:15:14.042: W/System.err(2586):         ... 15 more
```

Comment: What is the exact content of the exception, what do you see in logcat

Comment: @StefandeBruijn: Not that it matters it is SQLiteException for Constraint violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do get the SQLException but am not sure how do I handle this exception and ask the user to make changes.

You can certainly catch the exception and see if it is `instanceof SQLiteConstraintException` but I always hate treating exceptions as common occurrences.

What I would do is do a query on the user's input to see if there is an existing `MyInfo` object with the same fields.  Something like the following:

```
QueryBuilder<MyInfo, Integer> qb = mydao.queryBuilder();
qb.where().eq("COL1", myInfo.col1).and().eq("COL2", myInfo.col2);
if (qb.queryForFirst() != null) {
   // tell the user to enter unique values
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did but don't you think using multiple DB operations would affect performance besides Exceptions per se are meant to handle such cases, isnt it? I will try and use your first suggestion too.

Comment: Exceptions IMO are for "exceptional" conditions @PravinCG.  People use exceptions really to mean response codes sometimes which I don't like.  If this is validating user entered input then the extra DB operation should not affect the system at all.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for info. However on a more wider scale for ORMlite how do we track exception in the code as all the exceptions are wrapped and thrown as SQLException which makes it difficult to discern one from the other?

Comment: You can look at the cause of the exception I guess.  Another reason why using exceptions like this isn't optimal.  Since under the covers I'm dealing with X database types, I just wrap and rethrow and don't want to go through the dance of handling different Sqlite or Oracle exceptions differently @PravinCG.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way of doing it, but this can help to some one...

```
try {
        //insert to ORMLite
} catch (SQLException e) {
        validateException(e);
}
```

in the validateException method:

```
private void validateException(SQLException e) {
        try{
            if (e.getCause() == null)
                throw e;
            if (e.getCause().getCause() == null)
                throw e;
            if (e.getCause().getCause() instanceof SQLiteConstraintException)
                Log.d("Test", "Ignoring duplicate");
            else
                throw e;
        }catch(SQLException e1){
            //exception thrown by e;
        }
    }
```